# List all my deployed applications in Websphere and their respective ports

Tags: websphere, jython, administration, wsadmin

I want to administrate some things in my WebSphere Application Server using only command line, but I'm having troubles to get a list of my deployed apps and ports.

**What I want:**

I need to get a list of my depĺoyed apps and their ports. I'm new in the WAS administration and comparing with Apache Web Server I want something like the command `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`

Example of apachectl output:

> VirtualHost configuration:
>
> *:80                   mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site.conf:1)
>
> *:443                  secure.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/secure.conf:2)

*Note: I know that Apache and WAS is not the same thing (more similarities among WAS and Apache Tomcat) , but its just a example of my desired output: A list of my apps (virtual hosts in apache's example) and their respective ports*

**What I have until now:**

Since I need to do it from command line, I'm using the wsadmin shell following the steps below (Debian Server):

```
cd <Was_Root_Dir>/AppServer/bin
./wsadmin.sh -lang jython -user user -password pass
wsadmin>print AddminApp.list()
```

The result is like below:

> DefaultApplication
> site
> secure

That is the list that I want but I don't know the ports for each application and I can't find how to achieve it anywhere.

I think that list is extensive and include apps in all servers and all profiles of my WAS instance. Am I right here?

**Plus:**

A list with all deployed apps is pretty fine, but a plus could be a way of filter only apps that use the secure port with SSL.

Is it possible? Am I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use wsadmin listApplicationServerPorts command to list the ports, in order to access a particular application. See  IBM KC link ([listApplicationServerPorts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_atportmgt.html?view=kc#rxml_atportmgt__cmd2)) fro more details.

I have prepared a script for you, Copy and paste the below contents to a file (script.py) and run it using wsadmin, as given below

***./wsadmin.sh -lang jython -user user -password pass -f script.py***

```
#Get the list of ALL installed APPs
appList=AdminApp.list().splitlines()

#Get the list of Application ports for each APP
for app in appList:
    print "  "
    #print APP Name
    print app
    #Get the list of Application Ports
    portList=AdminTask.listApplicationPorts(app).splitlines()
    for port in portList:
        #Print the port Details for the APP
        print port
```

This would print the appName and the list of applicationports.

From this list, "***WC_defaulthost***" port can be used for **http** and "***WC_defaulthost_secure***" for **https**.